# Create user in existing sandbox from production login

Tags: sandbox, user-record, login, production, sandbox-refresh

I have production login credentials. I want to reset password of an User in an existing sandbox from production. If want possible I would like to create an User in sandbox from the production login. Please let me know if there is any wayout for that scenario.

Comment: Log into the sandbox and do it there. Why can you not do that?

Comment: My system admin User credentials for that sandbox is currently not working properly and I don't have anyone now who can reset that for me. Also my Email address is not correctly stamped that I will get forgot password link. It's a deadlock for other easy options for me now I guess

Comment: @Eric  Can you please help me here?

Comment: Not much I can do iy you forgot your password and cannot reset it. contact your admin to assist

Comment: You can't create user in sandbox from PROD. Try to login from PROD Setup->Sandboxs-> Select your Sandbox

Comment: even the u need the password